# Is the Dispilio tablet evidence of a pre-Sumerian and pre-Egyptian writing system?

Tags: ancient

**Sumerian tablets 3100bc**

The Sumerian tablets are widely recognised as the worlds earliest known writing system, dating to approximately 3100bc.

[Stages, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumerian_language#Stages)

> Archaic Sumerian is the earliest stage of inscriptions with linguistic content, beginning with the Jemdet Nasr (Uruk III) period from about the 31st to 30th centuries BC.

**Dispilio tablet**

Despite the fact that the Sumerian tablets are considered the earliest known writing system, the Dispilio tablet uncontroversially dates back to 5202bc.

[Dispilio tablet, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispilio_Tablet)

> The Dispilio tablet is a wooden tablet bearing inscribed markings, unearthed during George Hourmouziadis's excavations of Dispilio in Greece, and carbon 14-dated to 5202 (± 123) BC.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumerian_language#Stages) It was discovered in 1993 in a Neolithic lakeshore settlement that occupied an artificial island[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispilio_Tablet) near the modern village of Dispilio on Lake Kastoria in Kastoria, Western Macedonia, Greece.

**Question**

Is the Dispilio tablet evidence of a pre-Sumerian and pre-Egyptian writing system?

[Yorgos Facorellis, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispilio_Tablet#/media/File:Dispilio_signs.jpg)
[image: samples of signs on Paleo-European clay tablets.]

Comment: The picture has four columns, but only three markings, A, B, and C. Which corresponds to which? The second and the fourth column are almost the same.

Comment: The authors claim *If this
proves to be a primary source of written communication, the history of writing should be reconsid-
ered and Neolithic societies can no longer be considered “societies without writing.”* https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/radiocarbon/article/radiocarbon-dating-of-the-neolithic-lakeside-settlement-of-dispilio-kastoria-northern-greece/759AA29502776E142883F1971293BEB1

Comment: Not sure if the authors convinced me that the signs on that pottery "cannot be considered as decorative".

Comment: These characters look *very* Semitic. I'm skeptical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Could* this indicate a pre-cuneiform, pre-hieroglyphic writing system? It's possible, yes.

But so could the [Vinča symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vin%C4%8Da_symbols), or the [Jiahu symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiahu_symbols). It's hard to prove a negative (i.e. prove that these symbols *don't* encode language), but until someone can come up with a believable, systematic correspondence between these symbols and some form of language (a decipherment), it's more likely that these are proto-writing or just some form of decoration.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the wood dates back to 5200 bce but the inscription could have been carved at a later date. It could be someone found a nice piece of old, dried wood and used it to carve these inscriptions in an Era when other cultures were also using proto writing. It's possible. Need more evidence.